# How and why are PhD programs free in Europe?

Tags: phd, united-kingdom, europe

In some European countries, PhD programs are free. As I understand, PhD opening depends on the research funds of the supervisor. In other words, PhD research is funded by a national agency or EU.

Some countries offer the programs for free and an international student in the UK should pay about $20,000 per annum?

In addition to the research cost (which is funded through the same routes), a PhD student has other expenses for the university, which is provided by the tuition fee in the UK, while in countries with free PhD programs, the governments provides the supports (correct me if I am wrong).

My question is: Why/how such governments support PhD education of international students? And if it is reasonable, why isn't it the case in the UK?

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble with your phrasing. Do you mean "an international student in the UK must pay about ..." (probably pounds, not dollars, right)? And by "expenses for the university" do you mean fees due to the university from the PhD student?

Comment: @AzorAhai I cannot speak for the OP, but a PhD student needs physical space and uses the university resources.

Comment: @Googlebot I know, but I'm confused as to what they mean.

Comment: It is difficult to answer if you do not explain which expenses you mean. A PhD student in, say, mathematics, can work at home with their own computer. The supervisor's time is valuable, but, well, supervising is part of the academic work so it is somehow included in the salary.

Comment: If you're a fully funded PhD student in the UK, your tuition fees will be paid for you (essentially the same as a fee waiver). You will also be paid a stipend to cover living costs. Hence, the PhD is free. If you're not funded, you will have to pay tuition (undoubtedly more expensive for non-UK students, which is why it may be harder to get funding) and be able to support yourself.

Comment: *PhD research is funded by a national agency or EU* - Or from the regular university budget.

Comment: @Miguel The way advising is included in the salary of a professor is (usually) by charging tuition to the student. Even when a PhD is 'free' that tuition is being paid by someone.

Comment: @BryanKrause Do you mean that tuition fees result in a direct salary increase for the professor? This is certainly not the case in Spain. Then, I repeat my question: which *direct* expenses does the OP mean?

Comment: @Miguel I don't think the OP asked about any 'direct' expenses. I was referring to your statement: "supervising is part of the academic work so it is somehow included in the salary" in saying that yes, it's included in the salary because graduate students pay tuition (often that tuition is paid via other sources within the university, such as monies paid out for the student's work on grants). There isn't a magic pool of money that pays for "academic work." That isn't the same as saying that taking a student on gives a salary increase.

Answer (score 10):

I believe what you're talking about is the issue of *tuition waivers*: that is, are students obligated to pay fees for the tuition, or are those handled by the university.

In many countries in central Europe (including Scandinavia, Benelux, Germany, Switzerland, and Austria) PhD studies are actually paid employee positions, so what tuition charges exist are small, since students normally don't have to take many courses as part of the PhD program (international students may need to register for a few classes to satisfy qualification requirements, but it's not a coursework requirement *per se*). In other locales, such as as some programs in the US, grants cover tuition charges as well as stipends, preventing students from having to pay those charges. And in many of those countries, the tuition fees amount only to a few hundred euros, not tens of thousands.

It's only where students are expected to do large amounts of coursework *and* where no arrangements to remit or waive tuition are made that students are responsible for paying large amounts of tuition.

Comment: In France the situation is a bit more complex. "PhD students" (I do not see how to translate properly the actual title, *doctorant*) are paid employees. However, they must pay a tuition, even though their is no coursework, about 500€ per year I believe. However, some universities waive the tuition for students that are employees of the university, but not students that are employed by another organization (for example, these doing their PhD in collaboration with a private company and who are paid by the private company).

Comment: Generally speaking, the chance of an international student is much higher to get admission to a PhD programme, say in Sweden, than winning a scholarship in the UK. The latter is highly competitive and only a fraction of PhD students (both home and international students) receive full scholarships. Of course, after enrollment, there are various ways for compensation.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Technically, I believe most PhD students in Europe do have to pay some sort of registration fee—but the cost is on the order of hundreds of dollars per year, not tens of thousands, and there is some benefit received in exchange (for instance, students at my university in Northrhein-Westphalen got access to all public transportation in the state as part of it.)

Comment: I see. I had understood that PhD students in other countries don't pay tuition at all. So the situation seems to actually be more similar to France. (I'm not sure I got anything in exchange of my waived tuition, though; other than the piece of paper at the end, and a headache the first year.)

Comment: Europe is large and varied... even without the UK :) For instance in Spain PhD students are **not** employees per se (although many paid teaching/research assistants are expected to complete a PhD). In contrast, fees are negligible, say 60 euros per year.

Comment: "In most of continental Europe, PhD studies are actually paid employee positions" aeismail understanding of continental Europe and practices are different from mine, this is not first time we have disagreement, I dont know how or where he/she found these info, but it is not correct.

Comment: @SSimon Whether or not their paid positions, the important issue is that the tuition charges are not in the tens 9f thousands of Euros, and I don’t believe that is a controversial statement.

Comment: Well it would be much clearer to say "tuition costs are very small" instead of "there really isn't tuition to be charged".

Comment: I’ve done that now. Hopefully the new answer is clearer.

Comment: @Miguel Tuition fees in Spain *used* to be about 60 €/year. Nowadays they are about 500 €/year.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi for a short time, German universities in seven conservative federal states charged a tuition fee (Studiengebühr) for all students (not only on the PhD level), but currently the first degree is free in all federal states. A few states have permitted universities to charge a small fee for the second degree, for "excessively long" studies, and for non-EU foreigners. In sum, the situation in Germany is quite heterogeneous over time, across states, and even across universities. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studiengeb%C3%BChren_in_Deutschland#Urteil_des_Bundesverfassungsgerichts_2005

Comment: @NajibIdrissi but overall, the situation in Germany seems not too different from the one in France, as you describe it, i.e. the amounts are rather small and don't always have to be paid.

Comment: Actually™, the situation is more complex is Germany, too. While being a payed employee (typically: `wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter`, "a scientific employee") is one side to a PhD studies, being the _actual_ PhD candidate (`Doktorand`, the doctorate candidate) is the other. You can finance your PhD studies from some other source than being an employee. Being an employee does not guarantee in any way that you get your PhD. Depending on the money source, you might be required to do teaching as an employee. But typically your PhD supervisor and your work supervisor is the same person.

Comment: @Pere Maybe in some parts of Spain, in others it is 60,30 up to the current year http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/boja/2017/134/1

Comment: At least in Austria you can be a PhD student without being employed by the university (though it's rare to choose that path). However, simply being a PhD student puts a negligible strain on university resources - you don't get any working space, you don't have a right to a set amount of a professor's time (and the professor can decide whether or not to supervise you), ...

Comment: So the main reason that a PhD student needs to pay a large amount of money for tuition is the university expense derived from their course work? Then in UK, where PhD programs are divided into research type and course & research type, would people admitted into PhD programs of research type not be charged a big amount of tuition whether they are offered scholarships or not?

Answer (score 3):

Many people believe that education is not a commodity. They think that tuition fees are wrong and cannot be justified. While this belief may not be as widespread as it used to be, it is one of the most important reasons why many European countries charge low tuition fees or no fees at all.

There are also practical aspects. Many European countries are small, with often only one or two universities offering any particular subfield. Without sufficient international mobility, those subfields can easily become inbred. Governments often encourage universities to hire more foreign PhD students, researchers, and professors. Many politicians who otherwise support high tuition fees for foreign students prefer to keep PhD education free.

Let's assume that the typical cost of undergraduate education is €10,000/year to the university. PhD studies are more expensive, maybe €15,000/year, because the students need more one-to-one time with their supervisors. International PhD students are typically employed, which may cost €40,000 to €50,000/year. Then there are reseach expenses, which vary greatly depending on the field. Most of these expenses are ultimately paid by the government. If the university tries to pass a large fraction of tuition costs to the student, it becomes less attractive to foreign students, without reducing the overall cost to the public significantly.

Comment: "Many European countries are small, with often only one or two universities offering any particular subfield"... Really? Can you cite some examples of countries that small to support your claim that there are "many"?

Comment: @Miguel In my subfield of computer science: every European country except Germany, France, and the UK. Or at least that was the situation when I was looking for a place to do a postdoc. If a country has only 10-20 research universities, the chances are most PhDs in a particular research area come from the same departments.

Comment: Maybe we have different definitions of *subfield*. In Spain there are 52 public Universities, all of them are research institutions, and almost all of them have Computer Science departments. So, unless you demand excellence or have already focused on a very specialized *topic*, you have a wide choice. Anyway, the generic assertion "Many European countries are small" seems a bit US-biased.